# Anko layout on second activity doesn't show up

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I made a second activity via Anko layout which has an `ImageView` and 2 `TextView` for name and description. But those `TextView` doesn't show up. I think the code looks good but i don't know it still doesn't appear. Any solution?

**--The MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var items: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(activity_main)
        initData()

        club_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        club_list.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this,items){
            startActivity(intentFor<SecondActivity>(forto to it.clubName, forto to clubDesc, forto to it.clubImage))

        }
    }
    @SuppressLint()
    private fun initData(){
        val nameClub = resources.getStringArray(club_name)
        val descClub = resources.getStringArray(club_desc)
        val imageClub = resources.obtainTypedArray(club_image)
        items.clear()

        for (i in nameClub.indices) {
            items.add(Item(nameClub[i], descClub[i], imageClub.getResourceId(i, 1)))
        }
        imageClub.recycle()
    }
}
```

**const val forto = "com.my.app"**

**--SecondActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    linearLayout {
        orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        val image = intent.getIntExtra(forto, 1)

        imageView {
            topPadding = dip(16)
            imageResource = image
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = dip(100)) {
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL

            val namaClub = intent.getStringExtra(forto)

            textView {
                text = namaClub
                textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
            }.lparams(width = matchParent)
        }

        val clubDesc = intent.getStringExtra(forto)

        verticalLayout {
            textView {
                text = clubDesc
                padding = dip(16)
            }.lparams(width = matchParent)
        }
    }
}
```

**--Data class if you need it**

```
@Parcelize
data class Item (var clubName: String, var clubDesc: String, var clubImage: Int) : Parcelable
```

Comment: You will have to set layout using `setContentView` method

Comment: setContentView on Class? How?

Comment: In `onCreate()` method of your second activity

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity you have a textview inside the "lparams" block of the imageView. I suspect you meant to close out the lparams after you set the gravity.